# rpy2 how to check column data type

Tags: python, r, types, rpy2

I created pandas dataframe and converted it to R object using rpy2. Now I would like to check data type of a column. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

utils = importr('utils')
base = importr('base')

pd_df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3], 'col_2': [4,5,6]})

with (ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter).context():
    r_df = ro.conversion.get_conversion().py2rpy(pd_df)
```

Normally in R it would be

```
str(r_df$col_1)
```

I tried the following (nothing worked)

```
r_df$col_1
r_df['col_1']
r_df[1,1]
robjects.r['r_df']
robjects.r('''r_df''')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is call `class()`

In this case,

```
class(r_df$col_1)
```

should do the trick!

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Are you still working in Python?

Answer (score 1):

The R class (a vector of strings in R) can be accessed like this:

```
tuple(r_df.rclass)
```

(see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/robjects_robjects.html#rpy2.robjects.robject.RObjectMixin.rclass)

Extracting R list elements as done with either `$` or `[[` in R can be achieved with the method `.rx2()`:

```
tuple(r_df.rx2('col1').rclass)
```

(see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/vector.html#extracting-r-style)

Calling R's `str()` can be done with (note that printing to stdout is a side effect of that function):

```
 rpy2.robjects.globalenv.find('str')(r_df)
 # or
 rpy2.robjects.r('str')(r_df)
```